# Vue Jest testing issue : TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I am getting the issue  TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

update the babel and Bebel-jest packages also. but did solve.

vue version - 2.6.11

```
 import BaseAPI from '../BaseAPI'
 
class LanguageAPI extends BaseAPI {  // <-- issue
   _resource ='reference'
   _parentResources =['localization']
}
```

jest-conf.js

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost',
  testEnvironment: 'node'
}
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.3.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `BaseAPI`?

Comment: hey @tony19 
this the code of BaseAPI
```
import DefineInclude from '../../DefineInclude'
import AuthService from '../AuthService'
import Lodash from 'lodash'
import axios from 'axios'
import APIErrorHandler from '../APIHandler/APIErrorHandler'

export default class BaseAPI {}
```